# How to bypass Authorization in Swagger UI using springfox

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I need to bypass spring security when the request is coming from Swagger-UI, test environment. This is so we can test quickly without having to generate a new token every time since the data is test anyway.

My application is running on Spring Boot. I implemented Spring security so that user will have to provide a valid access token (header) in order to get a valid response, otherwise the application will return HTTP 401. It works well with Spring Fox but I need a way to turn off or at least provide a static token in Authorization so tester won't have to do it for every request.

I tried going through their documentation hoping to find a switch to turn it off specifically when the request is coming from Swagger UI.

I'm using: 
-Springboot 2.0.3
-springfox 2.8.0

Comment: using  profile we can make the thing work  ...... spring.profiles.active=swagger....and use webscurity and swagger security config separately and allow all urls in swagger configured security

Comment: Yes I am using spring profiles but I need to bypass only the request coming in for swagger and if a user will use a rest client ie: Postman, they should be required to provide the auth header since the request is not coming from swagger.

so for spring.profiles.active=swagger, allow requests from swagger but require authorization from everything else. I see this work in a C# framework hoping a similar functionality for Springfox.

Comment: I don't think this makes sense from a design perspective.  If you are allowing users to access the resources w/o authenticating via swagger, than why would you secure them when they hit the application from postman or other way.  I think the suggestion to use profiles is correct and then have 2 different build one where everything is open perhaps in dev and one where everything is secure like QA and higher enbironments.

Answer (score 1):

> using this one  ....

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

> or else

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll();
    return http.build();
}
```